# Including style sheets for different browsers without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, conditional-comments

I have a utility that scans through my css file and embeds images as base64 to reduce the amount of requests made to the server. Unfortunatly, IE does not support this.

I know how to include IE specific style sheets using conditional comments, but what about FF, Opera and Webkit? I don't want to give IE style sheets that it doesn't use.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to exclude the CSS from IE or to include it in a specific non-IE browser?

Comment: I'm trying to stop IE from downloading stylesheets with base64 encoded images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, (and if I don't), you can exclude CSS files from IE using conditional comments:

```
<![if IE 9]>
IE will ignore this; other browsers won't.
<![endif]>
```

Comment: Quote from OP: "I know how to include IE specific style sheets using conditional comments [...]"

Comment: @FRKT: Include, but not exclude.

Answer (score 2):

There are no conditional comments for Firefox, Opera and Safari. I'm unsure whether you may load stylesheets with Javascript, but I would recommend against it either way.

It's common to have a server-side scripting language like PHP determine the client and serve corresponding CSS files. In PHP, the user agent may be identified by parsing the contents of `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

If you're not comfortable with programming in PHP, there are a number of scripts that you could use. [This one](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/) seems particularly promising.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the user-agent in the web request, you could serve up a different style sheet in your HEAD tags.

Answer (score 0):

Instead.The best way to do is using the following.

type="text/safari"

type="text/chrome"

read the following post for better explaination.

http://webgyani.com/2010/03/how-to-serve-different-stylesheets-only-to-safari-and-chrome/

-Amit

Answer (score 0):

> Instead.The best way to do is using the following.
>   type="text/safari"
>   type="text/chrome"

Nooo, don't rely on browser bugs!
Chrome plans to fix this (and therefore disabling this hack) in version 50.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=286682

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/m/#!topic/blink-dev/nH1O6WszMgo